# Vue.js component van't see img

Tags: vue.js, webpack

I am doing weather application and I got a problem. here is my code

```
<template>
<div>
    <div><img :src="'../assets/' + icon" alt="weather icon"></div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
        computed:{
            icon(){
            switch (this.$store.getters.list[0].weather[0].icon) {
                case "01d":
                    return "day.svg"
                    break;
                case "01n":
                    return "night.svg"
                    break;
                case "02d":
                    return "cloudy-day-1.svg";
                    break;
                case "02n":
                    return "cloudy-night-1.svg";
                    break;
                case "03d":
                    return "cloudy-day-2.svg";
                    break;
                case "03n":
                    return "cloudy-night-2.svg"
                    break;
                case "04d":
                    return "cloudy-day-3.svg";
                    break;
                case "04n":
                    return "cloudy-night-3.svg"
                    break;
                case "09d" || "09n":
                    return "rainy-7.svg";
                    break;
                case "10d" || "10n":
                    return "rainy-1.svg";
                    break;
                case "11d" || "11n":
                    return "thunder.svg";
                    break;
                case "12d" || "13n":
                    return "snowy-6.svg"
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My path to images is working without v-bind if I use static path. But it doesn't work with dynamic path. Is it any problem with webpack? I checked the console elements tab and seems like path is correct.

Comment: What exactly is the problem you're getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok here I found a solution. 
 Should use require()

```
<div><img :src="'require(../assets/' + icon)" alt="weather icon"></div>
```